# Missing field in Apollo GraphQL Query

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo

I'm using react with Apollo and a F# backend.

When i make a query i get an error similar to this but i'm not sure why as it seems like stories is present in the response.

```
Missing field stories in "{\"stories\":[{\"name\":\"Story1\",\"__typename\":\"Story\"},{\"name\":\"Story2\",\"__typename\":\
```

My code for making the query is:

```js
const client = new ApolloClient({
    uri: '/graphql',
});

client
    .query({
        query: gql`
      query testStoryQuery
    {

        stories
        {
            name

        }

    }
    `
    })
    .then(result => console.log(result));
```

Finally the raw response returned by the server is:

```
{"data":"{\"stories\":[{\"name\":\"Story1\",\"__typename\":\"Story\"},{\"name\":\"Story2\",\"__typename\":\"Story\"},{\"name\":\"Story3\",\"__typename\":\"Story\"}]}"}
```

The only thing I've tried so far is jsonifying the response (i.e. the ") around fields, but it doesn't seem to find the field either way.

Update (extra info)

The full stack trace

[image: Stack trace of the browser error]

Any help would be appreciated, i'll continue working on it in the meantime.

Thank you :)

Comment: can you provide your schema?  tho to be honest it looks like you actually fixed whatever the issue was and just didnt refresh the page otherwise you'd be getting a 400 instead of that full response

Comment: @DanielRearden I'm able to query it normally through insomnia and postman (forgive me i'm not sure how to get GraphQLi working). I've updated the question with a stack trace. Thanks for the suggestions.  As per the client code above it's just to log, the code is based on the apollo-boost getting started code. After looking at the stack trace, it seems to be a problem with writeToStore, working on figuring out why.

Comment: @Deryck i'm not sure what format to post the schema in. Like the F# code defining it? The schema  has just one query stories and one of it's field is 'name'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bad response format:

> {"data":**____"____**{\"stories\":[{\"name\":\"Story1\",\"__typename\":\"Story\"},{\"name\":\"Story2\",\"__typename\":\"Story\"},{\"name\":\"Story3\",\"__typename\":\"Story\"}]}**____"____**}

This way data is a string, not object.

Also bad names `\r\n\t\t\t\t__typename` in a stack trace.

For more details run some working example (any apollo client project) and compare arguments passed to `writeToStore.ts` methods using browser debugger breakpoints.